# Integrate Salesforce with AutoDesk Inventor

Tags: salesforce, autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

How can we integrate Salesforce with AutoDesk Inventor? As Salesforce is cloud based and Inventor is a desktop based application, what options do we have to integrate Salesforce and Inventor? Do we have to use a middle-ware? If yes then which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page/) for Inventor you can automate processes with other cloud-based solutions.

Or have an Inventor desktop plugin that, upon an user interaction, read the current design and send data to your cloud-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk Inventor has documented COM API (.NET or C++). You can create AddIn for Inventor which can communicate with salesforce. You can create embedded web browser or call some salesforce API if any.